# How do I add validation for the edit text code in android?

Tags: android, validation

I am doing a programme for database. I have created three edit text for adding employee id, name and phone no. The issue is when I press add button without inserting any value the app crashes. How do i handle this? The following is the code which I have written.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.btn_add:

        Model india = new Model();
        india.id=Integer.parseInt(edit_empid.getText().toString());         // convet editable object from get text to string and then into integer
        india.name = edit_name.getText().toString();
        india.phone = edit_phone.getText().toString();


        db.addcontact(india);
        list = db.getAllContacts();
        print(list);
        edit_empid.setText(" ");
        edit_name.setText(" ");
        edit_phone.setText(" ");

        break;  

    case R.id.btn_delete:   

        long id = Long.parseLong(edit_empid.getText().toString());

        db.deletecontact(id);
        list = db.getAllContacts();
        print(list);

        break;

    case R.id.btn_update:   

        Model Japan = new Model();
        Japan.id=Integer.parseInt(edit_empid.getText().toString().trim());  
        Japan.name = edit_name.getText().toString();
        Japan.phone = edit_phone.getText().toString();

        int result = db.updatecontact(Japan);
        System.out.println("Print the update result " + result);
        list = db.getAllContacts();
        print(list);

        break;

    case R.id.btn_clear:

        edit_empid.setText(" ");
        edit_name.setText(" ");
        edit_phone.setText(" ");

        break;  






    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use `TextInputLayout`. Google introduced it in new design library. In order to use the TextInputLayout you have to add the following to your build.gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Then use it in your xml files:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter your name"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Before doing your database works check EditText value with if statement and if it is incorrect try:

```
TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout)    findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);
editText.setErrorEnabled(true);
editText.setError("You need to enter a name");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add an if statment of your input argument to check - isempty
Thats my guess

Answer (score 0):

User input is always evil! make that clear in your mind.  you can never trust users to put only the right stuff into your inputs. 
so just bounds check every input. If you want to get no empty strings check for it via

```
String input1 = edittext1.getText();
if(1 > input1.length()) {
    // tell user to check edittext1
} else {
    // do your update stuff
}
```

same stuff need to happen for every input.  if you e. g. try to get int values check em if they fit in your expected range and so on....

by this you don't need to put a space value into your editTexts while clearing em ...  (which need to be deleted by user if he wants to set the edittext correctly (-> evil user just ignores the space and enters its name and you will have to check for leading or ending sign of space before putting it in your database )

hint: regex strings to ensure input is correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent Library that handles Android Validation:

[Android Saripaar v2](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar)